# Azure spatial anchor(unity3d) - I am saving spatial anchor to cloud, but unable to locate it after 2 or 3 hours

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

Unity3d - Azure spatial anchor - I m using unity's azure spatial anchor sample project for sharing anchors. I have placed anchor on some location and saved to cloud. but after some hours I m unable to locate the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code sample is deleting the database. Please see Pull Request with the fix https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/pull/9/files

```
    if (!this.initializing.Wait(0))                 
    {                   
       this.initializing.Set();                     
       await this.dbCache.DeleteIfExistsAsync();\\ here the database gets deleted
       await this.dbCache.CreateAsync(); 

       this.initialized.Set();
    }
```

Edit: I saw that the pull request has been merged so the code sample in question should work.